# How to get device id in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

I'm working on Flash cs6 and actionscript3 and AIR 14.

How can I get the unique device id of a dektop, Android or iOS device?

Comment: Check [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/803428) out. Or use/write Native Extensions for every platform you need.

Comment: How can i use Native Extetension.please give me any clue.@Dodger Thud

Comment: Made question more compact and readable

Comment: possible duplicate of [AIR 3.5 Mobile project device ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131005/air-3-5-mobile-project-device-id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANE library FPUniqueId http://flashpress.ru/blog/ane/unique-id/?lang=en :

```
import ru.flashpress.uid.FPUniqueId;
//
trace('identifier: '+FPUniqueId.id);
trace('wifiMac: '+FPUniqueId.wifiMac);
//
switch (FPUniqueId.platform) {
    // iOS platform
    case 1:
        trace('keychainId: '+FPUniqueId.keychainId);
        break;
    //
    // Android platform
    case 2:
        trace('imei: '+FPUniqueId.imei);
        trace('phoneNumber: '+FPUniqueId.phoneNumber);
        trace('simSerialNumber: '+FPUniqueId.simSerialNumber);
        trace('bluetoothId: '+FPUniqueId.bluetoothId);
        break;
}
```